# Are kernel signals on Android ever benign?

Tags: android, android-ndk, signals

I've installed a native code crash reporting system in my Android app, based on signal processing. There's a bunch of sigaction() calls for all the popular crash causes, there's crash report dumping and sending home to the bug tracker.

I'm receiving pretty consistent reports about some signals that are definitely not in my code. There are multiple instances of SISSEGV that originates in android.view.GLES20Canvas.nDrawDisplayList. There's another that comes from within android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.sharedTimerFired.

Question: is there any chance those signals constitute normal program operation and won't cause a crash/termination if not caught by me? Naturally, I can't reproduce any of those at will. They happen on customer devices.

Comment: Is your app running in a Dalvik VM or Art?

Comment: Dalvik doesn't use any signals for normal operation, though it can handle SIGQUIT and SIGUSR1/2 for debugging functions.  I have seen OpenGL ES drivers from certain vendors capture SIGSEGV so that, if the shader compiler crashes, they can recover automatically.  I have heard that Art may catch SIGSEGV as a way to avoid explicit checks for NULL, but I don't know if it actually does that.  Generally speaking, though, in a Dalvik VM app you shouldn't see SIGSEGV unless something has gone wrong.